# Where did Rick get the matches?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead* season 1, episode 1 (maybe it was the pilot?) when Rick wakes up in the hospital he stumbles around looking at all the carnage until he heads toward the stairwell exit. In the stairwell in complete darkness he lights several matches. Where did he get these? I don't remember any scene where he picked these up. I can't imagine him having these while in a coma in his hospital bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to see because of the very dark lighting, but he picks them up from the nurses' station. After he fumbles around with the telephone he reaches into a plastic basket and moves his hands around. At approximately 17 minutes into season 1, episode 1, he grabs an object:

[image: grabbing the matches]

You can then see him swiping one hand across the other:

[image: lighting the matches]

Finally, he has a lit match.

[image: match is lit]

Based on this sequence and the shots in the stairwell, it is safe to assume he picked up a pack of matches and was using them for light given there is no electricity.

Answer (score 2):

might have found them somewhere. obviously. it was a hospital where the walkers were confined to a room. so definitely someone must have got some lights.

Answer (score 2):

I know what your talking about. The first episode of the Walking Dead Right? Obviously, in an entire hospital, there are going to be matches or something because of a possible power outage. That means that clearly, it makes sense that he found them.